# Как связать два сервиса через токен?

Tags: безопасность, шифрование

Существует веб-сервис авторизаций (A) и веб-сервис с секретной информацией (B). Существует веб-клиент, отправляющий POST-запрос на сервер A с логином и паролем. В случае успеха получает токен, который прикрепляет к запросам к сервису B. Сервис B считывает токен, и в случае валидности отдает секретную информацию на веб-клиент.

Вопрос: каким образом зашифровать токен, чтобы его нельзя было подделать на стороне веб-клиента? Какая логика должна быть на сервисах A и B, при условии, что они абсолютно не знают о существовании друг друга?

Comment: Если Вы зашифруете токен так, что веб-клиент не сможет его расшифровать, то как он будет вообще с ним работать? Или я не поняла вопрос...

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya задача веб-клиента в моем случае - просто передать тот токен, что выдал ему сервис A в случае успешной авторизации, вместе с остальной информацией. Сервис B должен понять, что этот токен именно от сервиса А и не является подделкой, при помощи какого-то алгоритма синхронного шифрования. Какого? Кроме всем известного алгоритма Диффи-Хеллмана (не подходит в моем случае)

Comment: Думаю, что сервис B все равно должен запрашивать данные у сервиса А напрямик для проверки токена пришедшего от пользователя.

Comment: @Visman в таком случае накладывается зависимость, что противоречит микросервисной архитектуре. Поэтому сервер A и B не знают друг о друге ничего. Такжен не связаны никаким общим хранилищем (redis и т.д.). Остается только способ с приватными и публичными ключами. Осталось выяснить правильный алгоритм для такой ситуации.

Comment: В токене нет информации о юзере. Или я не прав? Как сервис В узнает, какой юзер зашел с данным токеном, если не обратиться к сервису А?

Comment: @Visman в случае успешной авторизации, из сервиса A вместе с токеном передается id пользователя.

Comment: Несимметричное шифрование вам не нужно. Достаточно что бы токен в какой то своей части содержал информацию о пользователе и/или правах и срок действия в открытом или зашифрованном виде. Вторая часть токена должна быть на подобии электронной подписи. Например sha-1 сумма от первой части токена и некой секретной фразы которая известна только на серверах A и B. таким образом B всегда может проверить валидность токена проверив контрольную сумму. Без знания секретной фразы подделать токен невозможно

Comment: Я как-то делала кросс-доменную авторизацию. Но там нужно было только при входе на сервисе В проверить пользователя, а дальше с пользователем работал уже сервис А. Если интересно, был такой алгоритм: Сервис А генерировал "транспортный токен", который отправлял на Сервис В. Сервис В принимал от пользователя логин-пароль и если авторизация успешна, то генерировал авторизационный токен, который отправлял на сервис А, который в свою очередь перепроверял запросом на сервис В валидность токена и сервис А признавал пользователя своим. Как-то так, всё в коммент не уместить...

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! А что именно Вы подразумеваете под информацией о пользователе? Если ее можно подобрать теоретически методом перебора, то уже будет не важно, какая секретная фраза смешивается. Секретная фраза должна быть динамическим значением? Например, timestamp + соль в sha-1, или это не обязательно делать?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya Спасибо. Я понял алгоритм работы. Представьте, если у  Вас сервисов B станет очень много, все они находятся на разных машинах, со всеми вытекающими проблемами асинхронности передачи сообщений между ними. В конечном счете все начнет обрастать связями, нужно обращаться в сервис А перед совершением каких-либо операций.

Comment: @MatveySafronov Фраза постоянна. Иначе как B поймет какая фраза нужна для проверки. А информацию о пользователе пусть подбираюст сколько хотят. Изменение любого бита этой информации ведет к необходимости правильно вычислить sha1, а без знания фразы это невозможно. Хотя конечно лучше зашифровать данные любым симметричным алгоритмом

Comment: [JWT](https://jwt.io/)? Взгляните.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервис A и B имеют секретную фразу, которая смешивается с информацией о пользователе и преобразовывается в SHA-1 строку. Сервисы пишутся на nodejs, и я использовал пакет "jsonwebtoken".

На сервисе A мы генерируем jwt:

```
const SECRET_PHRASE = 'test';
let token = jwt.sign( { foo: 'bar' }, SECRET_PHRASE );
console.log( token ); // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJpYXQiOjE0Njg4Njg1MzJ9.WzCfkIs4BkavFUUzEBS62FT-W9ZOMUVfXiSaRF5J3H8
```

На сервисе B - декодируем:

```
let decoded = jwt.verify( token, SECRET_PHRASE );
console.log( decoded ); // { foo: 'bar', iat: 1468868532 }
```

Спасибо @Mike и @D-side