# Как правильно организовать защиту сервиса?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth2

Имеется одно приложение, представляющее из себя RESTfull сервис, назовем его сервисА (хранит польователей и зарегистрированые сервисы). Второй сервис (сервисБ) использует сервисА для поиска пользователей. На нем хранятся их роли. И есть UI с обычной формой входа, куда пользователь вводит логин\пароль.
Все сервисы на Java Spring.

То есть логин и пароль попадают в сервисБ, который делает запрос на аутентификацию в сервисА, если А подтверждает аутентификацию, то сервисБ смотрит роли этого пользователя и разрешает\запрещает ему делать определенные действия.
Напрямую пользователь в сервисА обращаться не должен.

Интересно, какие протоколы использовать для обеспечения защиты такой архитектуры? Вроде похожее взаимодействие описывает OAuth2, но в нем, насколько я понимаю, пользователь образщается к сервисуА и там получает уже права на действия в сервисеБ, так ли это?

Comment: Похожая ситуация: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/546020/181100

Comment: @D-side не совсем то что нужно, мой сервисА никакой секретной информации в общем-то не хранит. Он просто проверяет есть ли пользователь в базе ( по сути является сервисом аутентификации). В свою очередь сервисБ - сервис авторизции ( На основе подтверждения аутентификации от сервисаА)

Comment: Похоже, и у вас даже проще: сервисуБ **доверяются** учётные данные. Собственно, всё, что есть по ссылке -- способ оформить "подписанное временное удостоверение", это может вам понадобиться.

Answer (score 2):

Любое банальное защищённое соединение с удостоверением каждой из сторон.

Например, **HTTPS + клиентский SSL**. Здесь главное не потеряться в сертификатах. Поскольку вам не нужно, чтобы этим сертификатам доверял внешний мир, подписывать его у "широко уважаемых удостоверяющих центров" нет необходимости, хватит самоподписанных.

- Генерируем самоподписанный **серверный сертификат**.
- Генерируем самоподписанный **CA** (Certificate Authority, "удостоверяющий центр") для **клиентских сертификатов**.
- Генерируем **клиентский сертификат** и подписываем его с помощью CA из предыдущего пункта.

Когда наиграетесь с сертификатами и ключами, надо будет настроить компоненты системы на их использование:

- HTTP-**клиент** *сервисаБ* должен при установлении HTTPS-соединения с *сервисомА* проверить, что сервер представился известным серверным сертификатом **и никаким другим** (системным CA в этом случае доверять нельзя!). Сам сертификат ему для этого не нужен: достаточно **публичного ключа от серверного сертификата**.
- HTTP-**сервер** *сервисаА* должен проверять, что клиентский SSL-сертификат выдан **вышесгенерированным CA** и **никем другим**. Для этого ему, предположительно, надо знать публичный ключ этого CA. К сожалению, на этом область моей компетенции заканчивается.

Когда это есть, обе стороны знают, что они именно те, за кого себя выдают, за безопасность передаваемых данных мало оснований беспокоиться. Надёжность соединения опирается на сохранность ключей CA и сертификатов от злоумышленников.

Я рассчитываю, что ожидается схема "один сервисА - много сервисовБ". В зависимости от того, где "много", а где "один", может иметь смысл заменить связку {CA}+{его сертификаты} на просто {самоподписанный сертификат} или наоборот.